# Reading a text file from accessible c$ computer on the same network using python

Tags: python, samba

I have a computer (A) on the same network that I can access and copy its files through \\[ip of A]\c$ after entering the username and password into prompt credentials window as shown in the image below.

[PIC 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVUB5.png)

I am trying to do that through python script that can read that text file remotely or at least copy it to my desktop (B).

Keep in mind there's a network firewall and limitations and need to do it through the same port when I do it manually as shown in the image above.

Could that be feasible? Appreciate your thoughts and feedback!

Thanks,

Comment: If Windows Explorer displays the location as `\[ip of A]\c$` then that's a samba connection, not ftp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access remote files on server with smb protocol python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493699/access-remote-files-on-server-with-smb-protocol-python3)