# How to programmatically access file from shared network folder and upload to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can any one help me on how we can programmatically read files from shared network folder[path - smb://ant/xxtest] and upload to S3.

If there is already any package in python or Java, please share with me it would be more helpful.

Thanks

I explored to use AWS Storage gateway & data sync but it did resolve the problem

Comment: What is your specific issue? Are you unable to access the source file from a program, or are you unable to upload to S3? For example, can your program read the contents of a file in that network path?

Comment: i'm looking for a sample code in python or java for reference to achieve my usecase.

Comment: There are lots of code examples on the Internet showing how to use Amazon S3. Have you tried any of it? Do you have a _specific_ issue?

Comment: Not about S3 , i want some samples on how to read & copy the files from shared network folder

Comment: Do a web search. There is plenty of information, eg: [python - access remote files on server with smb protocol python3 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493699/access-remote-files-on-server-with-smb-protocol-python3)